# busqueda de registros (clientes) en especifico - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

actualmente estoy intentando realizar una busqueda de clientes que hayan cancelado todas las cuentas pero absolutamente todas en un rango de fecha, por ejemplo si un cliente tiene 10 cuentas y cancelo 9 entonces en esa busqueda no me deberia de aparecer, pero si un cliente tiene 10 cuentas y cancelo las 10 entonces que si me aparezca en mi consulta

Este es mi query actualmente:

```
DECLARE @FechaInicio DATE;
DECLARE @FechaFin DATE;

SET @FechaInicio='2021-01-31';
SET @FechaFin='2021-02-28';

SELECT 
c.FullnameLocal AS [Nombre Cliente],
c.TaxCode AS [Identidad],
COUNT(con.ContractNumber) AS [Numero Cuentas],


FROM dbo.Clients C

OUTER APPLY(
SELECT DISTINCT ccr.ContractNumber, co.CloseDate, co.ContractStatusId
FROM dbo.CustomerContractRelations ccr
INNER JOIN dbo.Contracts co ON co.ContractNumber = ccr.ContractNumber 
WHERE ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId AND co.ContractStatusId  NOT IN ('1','2')
)con
 
GROUP BY c.FullnameLocal,c.Created,c.TaxCode,con.CloseDate
```

En dicho query extraigo el nombre, id y cuantas cuentas tiene el cliente con un count, lo que no se es como hacer para que en este query me aparezcan unicamente los clientes que hayan cancelado TODAS las cuentas en un rango de fecha que coloco en las variables

La siguiente tabla contiene la informacion del estado de las cuentas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cual seria la forma de filtrar, si todas las cuentas de un cliente tienen estado 4,5 y 6 entonces ya estan cancelados y deberian de aparecer en la consulta del query

con una cuenta de un cliente que tenga estado 1 y 2 entonces ya no deberia de aparecer en el query

si en un rango de 1 mes, hay 2 clientes:

- El 1er cliente tiene 5 cuentas de ahorro, cancelo 4, entonces ese cliente no me deberia de aparecer en la consulta
  -el 2do cliente tiene 3 de cuentas de ahorro, en ese laptop de tiempo cancelo las 3, entonces si deberia de aparecer en la consulta

Alguien que me ayude y me salve la vida ya que no se como realizar esta validacion

Comment: ¿Y donde entran las fechas? ¿Qué pasa si un contrato estuvo abierto en esas fechas pero ahora está cerrado?

Comment: los contratos tienen una fecha de creacion y fecha de cierre, entonces esa seria la fecha,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías contar la cantidad de cuentas en dicho periodo y la cantidad de cuentas canceladas en dicho periodo, si coinciden lo muestras en el resultado, caso contrario no.

Para ello tendrías que agregar en tu query la cláusula `HAVING` para filtrar luego de agrupar utilizando la función de agregación `count(*)`:

```
HAVING count(*) = count(CASE WHEN co.ContractStatusId IN (4,5,6) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

De esta manera cuentas el total de cuentas por cliente `count(*)` y lo comparas con el total de cuentas canceladas por cliente `count(CASE WHEN co.ContractStatusId IN (4,5,6) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)`.

Tienes que sacar del `WHERE` la restricción: `AND co.ContractStatusId NOT IN ('1','2')` para que retorne todas las cuentas.

Tienes que filtrar por las fechas en el `WHERE` y no agrupar por las fechas.

Tu query debería quedar parecida a esta, no cuento con el modelo de datos, por lo tanto no la puedo probar:

```
SELECT 
      c.FullnameLocal AS [Nombre Cliente],
      c.TaxCode AS [Identidad],
      COUNT(con.ContractNumber) AS [Numero Cuentas]

FROM dbo.Clients c
INNER JOIN dbo.CustomerContractRelations ccr ON  ccr.ClientId = c.ClientId 
INNER JOIN dbo.Contracts co ON co.ContractNumber = ccr.ContractNumber 

WHERE co.Created >= '2021-01-31' AND co.CloseDate <= '2021-02-28'

GROUP BY c.FullnameLocal, c.TaxCode

HAVING count(*) = count(CASE WHEN co.ContractStatusId IN (4,5,6) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END);
```